# What does "NFC Connectivity (Optional)" mean for the Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II?

Tags: hardware, settings, nfc, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I'm considering to buy a Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II. In the specs, I've read "NFC Connectivity (Optional)". What does that mean?

It seems that the first batch of phones won't have an NFC chip. Is it possible to retrofit one or will have I have to buy a new phone for NFC?

Comment: I haven't look into it, but I would assume there are two different chipsets.  If that's the case you'd probably be out of luck with the NFC-less version.

Comment: Being able to retrofit any hardware to a modern mobile phone seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: So? The Palm had a slot where you could add a wifi card. Almost all smartphones have slots for microSDHC cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means some models have the NFC chip, and some don't. From what I understand, at the moment, only the model released in South Korea has the NFC chip. My model (from the UK) doesn't have it.

Though I've been following SGS2 news, I haven't read anything about the possibility of retrofitting a chip later - either you have it or you don't.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Obviously not what I wanted to hear but at least an answer :-)